# 2.4GHz Layout and Tuning to 50OHMs

Tags: rf, layout, impedance-matching

My 2.4GHz circuit is as follows:

*(a)BLE (nRF51) -> (b)Balun -> (c)uFL -> (d)50OHM coax -> (e)matched-antenna*

Does it even make sense to put a pi-match between b and c, so it can be tuned? My understanding is that I don't need to at all, and its best to go from b to c directly without a match.

Comment: If you don't mess up the balun it can be used to directly match to 50Ω

Comment: The filter not only matches impedances in the passband, but attenuates harmonics in the stopband, best to follow a reference design.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 unfortunatly the ref design uses a printed antenna, where you MUST use a pi-network. Also, I believe the antenna already acts like a filter, as it will pass everything in the passband, and reject everything in the stopband.